# Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProject'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Вчера 15/02/16 возникла ошибка проекта:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyProject'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta4.
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta4/gradle-2.0.0-beta4.pom
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta4/gradle-2.0.0-beta4.jar
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta4/gradle-2.0.0-beta4.pom
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.0.0-beta4/gradle-2.0.0-beta4.jar
Required by:
:MyProject:unspecified
```

Пробовал решения из [этой статьи](http://habrahabr.ru/post/270479) -  не помогли.

Проект создавался с помощью `gdx-setup` библиотека Gdx.
При переходе по ссылкам через браузер 404 ошибка.
В `build.gradle` добавлял `jcenter()` - не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение: проверив изменение версии через git history,
 внимательно изучив все строки за последние несколько дней, нашел изменение которое я не делал:
 в проекте в файле проекта \gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties

в строке 
distributionUrl=

вчера было изменение с http на https, поменяв данную строку обратно на

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip

Еще в файл build.gradle проекта в раздел buildscript - repositories  { необходимо добавить строку `jcenter() {url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}`  
`
Получится приблизительно следующее:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

    jcenter() {url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}

    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
    }
}
```

`

Все заработало.