# Не запускается Desktop-версия проекта на LibGDX

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

Доброго времени суток! Недавно начал изучать фреймворк LibGDX. Android-версия проекта запускается. А вот при запуске desktop-версии возникает ошибка.

В чём проблема и как её исправить?
Desktop-конфигурация вот: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот сама ошибка:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Rogalik_1'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-beta3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https:// repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-beta3/gradle-2.1.0-beta3.pom
>            https:// repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-beta3/gradle-2.1.0-beta3.jar
>            https:// oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-beta3/gradle-2.1.0-beta3.pom"
>            "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-beta3/gradle-2.1.0-beta3.jar
>        Required by:
>            :Rogalik_1:unspecified

На всякий случай, код build.gradle(Module.desktop):

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "ru.artur.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
        }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
     }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Comment: тут проверьте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494144/180022

Comment: @АндроидАндроид,  не помогло(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ошибку, во время построения проекта самой LibGDX я не поставил галочку напротив пункта IDEA в меня Advanced:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]